# Pop Up message is not open

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, popup

when i am using set_flashdata() function or print() before the redirect() function in CodeIgniter. it's not working.

what's the reason behind this or can i use another function to popup the message on the screen.

Comment: $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);
redirect('myaccount',$data);
in this code, only page redirect but pop-up not their

Comment: first did you call session library or put it on autoload?

Comment: yes, i call the session library before the function calling.
$this->load->library('session');

$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);

Comment: Are you using `$this->session->flashdata('msg');` to read the session variable when redirect?

Comment: no, i am using
$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg); "set_flashdata" to read the variable.

Answer (score 0):

To add flashdata:

`$this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);`

To read a flashdata variable:

`$this->session->flashdata('msg');`

You can check the documentation [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)